# Hibernate - 'this' keyword added in inbuilt functions

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime, hsqldb

I'm using spring,hibernate,mysql in my project. I would to like to test my DAO with HSQLDB.

I am using @Formula(org.hibernate.annotations.Formula) annotation to achieve age calculations.This works in mysql,not in hsql.

Hibernate automatically added 'this' or 'patient0_(pojo)' in my query. I attached sample example find below.

PATIENT POJO:

```
@Formula("(CASE  WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, '2010-11-29 13:13:55', '2010-11-29 13:16:55') THEN NULL ELSE NULL  END)")
private String age;
```

Executed Query

```
(CASE  
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(patient0_.year,
        '2010-11-29 13:13:55',
        '2010-11-29 13:16:55') THEN NULL 
        ELSE NULL  
    END) as formula1_1_,
```

I also tried with

1 . \"year\" (returns patient0_"year")

2 . [year]  (returns unexpected '[' )

How to resolve this ?

Comment: what is the exception ? Did you change the driver and the dialect in your test configuration ?

Comment: Exception:" unexpected token: THIS_"

Comment: Yeah !. I've changed config and driver.. All queries executed well except queries in @Formula

Comment: Hibernate uses the prefix for all names in a Formula that are not recognized as _keywords_. And the MySQLDialect defines the `year` keyword, while the `H2Dialect` doesn't. See [my answer here](/questions/32688660)..